# How can the running head on recto pages in table of contents be removed (in KOMA)?

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, koma-script

I am writing a thesis work in **scrbook** class (though it appears this applies to similar non-KOMA classes as well).

The default behavior for running head is:

> Verso pages: Chapter Title
>
> Recto pages: Section Title

If there is no corresponding section, running head on verso remains blank. Being typeset as a chapter, this also applies to the bibliography for instance.

What bothers me in terms of consistency is that in the table of contents, which also uses Chapter style headings and spacing, different behavior is adopted:

> Verso and Recto pages: "Contents"

Within the table of contents, I am therefore looking for a way to remove the running head from recto pages.

So far I have dug several levels into the **\tableofconents** command using **\show** but still have no clue which macros to redefine in order to get the desired behavior.

Here is some minimal working example to illustrate the description above:

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter Heads Appear on Verso}
\section{Section Heads Appear on Recto} \subsection{Subsection}\lipsum[1-3] \subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection}  \subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section} \subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}

\chapter{Recto Heads are blank without section}
\lipsum[1-3]

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section} \subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection}\subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section} \subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section} \subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection}\subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section} \subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section} \subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section} \subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section} \subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection}\subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section} \subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert

```
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\markright{}}
```

in your preamble.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{scrbook}
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\markright{}}% < --- added

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter Heads Appear on Verso}*
\section{Section Heads Appear on Recto} \subsection{Subsection}\lipsum[1-3] \subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection}  \subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section} \subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}

\chapter{Recto Heads are blank without section}
\lipsum[1-3]

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section} \subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection}\subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section} \subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section} \subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection}\subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section} \subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section} \subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section} \subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section} \subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection}\subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section} \subsection{Subsection} \subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\end{document}
```

If you want the same behavior in LOF and LOT and maybe other lists controlled by package `tocbasic` you can use

```
\AfterTOCHead{\markright{}}
```

Comment: Even better that there is a simple solution without redefining any macros, making it more portable across different classes.